# Display SharePoint list Hyperlink column Value Using JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, jsom

- I am displaying the SharePoint List items based on ID value using
  **JSOM**.
- And among the list columns there is `"Hyperlink"` column which is
  showing the value as `"[object Object]"` when retrieving

Can any one help me how can I get the `Description` and it's `Url` for a `Hyperlink` column using **JSOM**

Answer (score 7):

Hyperlink is a `object`. You can get its property by following

## For description

```
listItem.get_item("{column internal name}").get_description()
```

## For Url

```
listItem.get_item("{column internal name}").get_url()
```

Comment: Just a tip, if they don't have values, the field will return as `null` value.  `(listItem.get_item("{column internal name}") != null ) ? listItem.get_item("{column internal name}").get_url() : ""`

Comment: Dear Atish,Thanks for your support .I need combination of both as single value. and I am getting  "Error as : The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested."

Comment: Yes @AndersAune. **OP** needs this checking if his field is optional.

Comment: You need to load the item before accessing it. Can you share your code so that I can help you more. @MSA